# Passing elements of a slice to `fmt.Println` using the `...` operator to spread arguments doesn't work. Why?

Tags: go, variadic-functions

I have an array/slice of elements (bytes in my example), and I want to print these values using `ftm.Println`. I can of course just loop over the elements in the array and print them that way, but I thought it would be nicer/shorter if I just passed the elements using `...` operator instead.

So I tried this:

```
    b := []byte{1,2,3,4}
    fmt.Println(b...)
```

This results in an error:

> cannot use b (variable of type []byte) as type []any in argument to fmt.Println"

Can someone explain why that doesn't work?

I was assuming that `fmt.Println` is a variadic function that is capable of handling any number of elements of any type (the `[]any` in the error message seems to suggest that is the case). So it is a bit surprising to me that `Println` seems not capable of handling it when I pass it 4 bytes.

Indeed when we pass these same bytes like this it works just fine:

```
    fmt.Println(b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3])
```

So why doesn't it work when use `b...` instead? Isn't that essentially the same thing (i.e. in both cases what we are doing is passing 4 bytes as separate arguments to `fmt.Println`?

Comment: Thats a thing in go. []byte != []any.

Comment: That makes sense for when you are passing `[]byte` to a function that expected a `[]any` as an argument, because the function could then write stuff into the `[]byte` that isn't a byte. But when using it in varargs, I don't think that should matter. (Since we are not passing an array but passing just individual values).

Comment: `fmt.Println(b...)` does not pass individual elements.

Comment: Its also somewhat adressed in the FAQ https://go.dev/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface. It's because they have a different memory layout. It also trips be up tbh. But you learn to live with it, I guess.

Comment: But neither does `fmt.println(b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3])` does it? I mean the answer below implies that these get turned into a slice and passed. So it passes a slice in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variadic arguments are passed as a slice. In the following:

```
fmt.Println(b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3])
```

The compiler creates a slice `[]any` from the four elements, and passes that slice.

However,

```
b := []byte{1,2,3,4}
fmt.Println(b...)
```

tries to pass a `[]byte`, which is not compatible with the function signature.

This works though:

```
b := []any{1,2,3,4}
fmt.Println(b...)
```

`[]byte` cannot be substituted for `[]any` because a byte array is structurally different from an interface array. Thus, an element-by-element conversion is necessary, which can be expensive. In general, Go language does not perform implicit conversions that can be expensive. If you need to do it, then you have to make it explicitly yourself.

Comment: I suppose that all makes sense in a way, but it still doesn't quite scratch the itch that this feels illogical. I.e. if the compiler can make a slice from the individual values, why can't it also make a slice of `[]any` from a a slice of `[]byte` ?

Comment: Creating a `[]any` from `[]byte` is an expensive operation. It requires creating a new slice and iterating through it. Go compiler does not perform potentially expensive implicit operations. If you want it, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Okay that sort of makes sense, go doesn't do it because it would be too expensive. Maybe that ought to be part of the answer?

Comment: I've upvoted, but will wait to accept a answer that is more complete (i.e. explains more explicitly what we discussed in these comments, that... while technically/logically it would be possible to make this work by creating a `[]any` from the values in the `[]byte`, golang doesn't do this because ...

Comment: Added that comment to the answer